# Authentication doesn't work in heroku Omniauth/Devise gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

i finished the creation of my web. So i'm very happy.
BUT.. here is the thing, today i tried to deploy it on heroku. Here is the link:

https://nameless-wildwood-94934.herokuapp.com/

I Migrated to postgreSql since heroku doesn't support sql, i also changed this line:

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

to

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'https://nameless-wildwood-94934.herokuapp.com' }

However the login(simple way/facebook/gmail) doesn't work, but with logs it seems that it does the insertion in the database so i guesse it's related to omniauth/devise gems which handle all these. Please can you suggest me a solution.

Thanks
THANK YOU

Comment: Have you changed the callback URL in your Facebook app? You need to direct that to your new Heroku instance as well.

Comment: Have you restarted your dynos?

Comment: No, i just read about dynos and i dont' see how it can affect the authentication ?

Comment: You should check the logs on Heroku, to see if Facebook is calling your callback function, this is not the solution but at least tells you where the problem is.